# 24 hours time format

Tags: c, strptime

I am reading a json in a C program. I receive a string like this:

```
Apr 3, 2014 4:44:39 PM
```

I am parsing it with `strptime` to get all values like this:

```
strptime(observationDate, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p", &result);
```

I tried also with `%r` instead of `%p`. In observationDate I have the string containing the date in string format. result is a struct tm.

But, even getting PM in the first string, when I try to print the date after conversion I get 4 instead of 16.I print like this, debugLog is a function to print the system date before text...

```
debugLog(DEB_INFO, "observationDateConverted: %d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d\n", 
                    result.tm_year+1900, 
                    result.tm_mon + 1, 
                    result.tm_mday, 
                    result.tm_hour, 
                    result.tm_min, 
                    result.tm_sec);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `%r` **or** `%I:%M:%S %p` (note it's `I` not `H`).

From [`man strptime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) (emphasis by me):

> %r
>   The 12-hour clock time (using the locale's AM or PM).  In the POSIX locale ***equivalent to %I:%M:%S %p***.

The lesson learned here: [RTFM!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)

Test program:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <time.h>

const char d[] = "Apr 3, 2014 4:44:39 PM";

int main(void)
{
  struct tm t = { 0 };

  strptime(d, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p", &t);
}
```

Checking the result:

```
$gdb ./main
[...]
b 12
r
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:12
12  }
(gdb) p t
$2 = {tm_sec = 39, tm_min = 44, tm_hour = 16, tm_mday = 3, tm_mon = 3, tm_year = 114, tm_wday = 4, tm_yday = 92, tm_isdst = 0, __tm_gmtoff = 0, __tm_zone = 0x0}
(gdb)
```

Comment: But I don't want 12-hour clock time. I want 24 because on PM, I want to receive 16 or 17 for example

Comment: `strptime()` parses an input string. As you get 12h time format on input so use the correct format specifiers for what you get, which is 12h am/pm. the `struct tm` then will be set corretly.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. I was reading data using the wrong parameter. I wans't understanding how it works.